# JSON key reducer and formatter in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am facing a situation where it seems helpful to have a gem that can format the JSON that comes as a response from any API. For example I may make a call to fetch some data but I don't need all the fields, instead I need to create a new JSON by parsing the original one to only include some fields and also be able to select only some of nested fields from arrays or array of arrays inside that JSON. The result of the reduced JSON can be a JSON that has only one level of nesting.
Can you please help me if there is an existing gem in Ruby to do this?

I am showing an example to explain better my situation.

Original JSON:

```
[{
  "key1": "test",
  "key2": "Test",
  "key3": "Test",
  "key4": [
    "key1": "test"
  ],
  "key5": [
    "key6": "test",
    "key7": [
      {"key8": ["test", "test"]},
      {"key8": ["test2", "test3"]}
    ]
  ]
}]
```

And after executing some function, for example:

```
select(["key1", "key2", "key5.key6.key7.key8"])
```

The result would be:

```
[{
   "key1": "test",
   "key2": "Test",
   "key8": [
     "test", "test", "test2", "test3"
   ]
 }]
```

Comment: Can you please provide an input example and an expected output?

Comment: @spickermann thank you for your response. I updated my question, including an example.

Comment: Minor comment regarding your "Original JSON" object: While that object is valid ruby literal syntax for Array and Hash, it is neither valid JSON or a ruby representation (inspection) of that Object.

Comment: @johnbowlee I have deleted my answer for now until you can provide a clearer explanation of the rules that govern this deconstruction and reconstruction.